# D3 js what kind of scale to use for unbalanced data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale, data-visualization

I have to render few circles on which "r" attr depends on the input data. The problem with input data is one of the value is so huge compared to rest of the data points that when i use scaleLinear | Pow | Log with range 2 - 35 ; all my circles have radius between 2 - 3 and only that few data points are radius 35. so what kind of scale can i use for such data for better visual ?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe use [d3.scaleQuantize](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#scaleQuantize).
Here is the example provided by the documentation:

```
var width = d3.scaleQuantize()
    .domain([10, 100])
    .range([1, 2, 4]);

width(20); // 1
width(50); // 2
width(80); // 4
```

Or you could write your own classification function. Something like this (with 3 classes here):

if input data < x => r = 2

else if  x <= input data < y => r = 8

else (input data >=y) => r = 14